# Scalajs-react: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scala.js, scalajs-react

I have following code for my scalajs-react application:

```
def render(person: Person) = {
    <.div(
      <.p("Welcome!"),
      <.form(
        <.label("Name:",
          <.input(^.`type` := "text", ^.cls := "form-control",
            ^.value := person.name, ^.onChange ==> updatePersonName
          )
      ))
    )
  }

  def updatePersonName(event: ReactEventFromInput): Callback = {
    $.modState(person => person.copy(name = event.target.value))
  }
```

But I see error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

you have use `event.extract`

Doc says:

> If you want to access the event properties in an asynchronous way (eg. in a `modState(…)` function)

Therefore your `updatePersonName` function should look:

```
def updatePersonName(event: ReactEventFromInput): CallbackTo[Unit] = {
  event.extract(_.target.value)(text =>
    $.modState(person => person.copy(name = text))
  )
}
```